# Classes in Python

Tags: python, image, class, image-processing, printing

I have completed phase 1 and started phase 2 which requires creating a function that can l flip the picture horizontally. That is, the pixel that is on the far right end of the row ends up on the far left of the row and vice versa (remember to preserve RGB order!).- I have done this but I did this as a function outside the class. I need to put the function back in the class and use the information that is already loaded in the class. How can I do this. I also need help with applying all of the functions (flatten red, greyscale, and horizontal flip) to one file and only writing the resulting code to the file once  all of the functions have been applied.  Please keep in mind, I am only 11 so I don't have an advanced understanding of Python and Image editing

```
class PPM(object):
    def __init__(self, infile, outfile):
        self.infile=infile
        self.outfile=outfile

        #Read in data of image
        data= open(self.infile,"r")
        datain=data.read()
        splits=datain.split()

        #Header info
        self.type=splits[0]
        self.columns=splits[1]
        self.row=splits[2]
        self.colour=splits[3]
        self.pixels=splits[4:]

    def greysscale():
            for row in range(rows):
                for column in range(columns):
                    r, g, b = image.getPixel(row, column)
                    brightness = int(round(0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b))
                    image.setPixel(row, column, color_rgb(brightness, brightness, brightness))


    def flip_horizontal(input,output):
        data= open(self.infile,"r")
        datain=data.read()
        splits=datain.split()

        type_of_ppm = splits[0]
        no_of_columns = splits[1]
        no_of_rows = splits[2]
        max_color_value = splits[3]
        pixels = splits[4:]
        #print pixels

        dataout = open(output, 'w')
        dataout.write(type_of_ppm + '\n')
        dataout.write(no_of_columns + ' ' + no_of_rows + '\n')
        dataout.write(max_color_value +'\n')
        if int(no_of_columns) > 1000:
            return "ERROR!! Number of columns is larger than what can be held in a buffer."
        else:
            temp_list = []
            for b in range(int(no_of_rows)):
                column_list = []
                column_list += pixels[0:int(no_of_columns) * 3]
                pixels = pixels[int(no_of_columns) * 3 : ]
                temp_list.append(column_list)
            #print temp_list
            new_list = []
            for i in range(int(no_of_rows)):
                for j in range(int(no_of_columns)):
                    new_list.append (temp_list[i][-3])
                    new_list.append (temp_list[i][-2])
                    new_list.append (temp_list[i][-1])
                    temp_list[i] = temp_list[i][:-3]
            #print new_list
            for a in range(int(no_of_columns) * int(no_of_rows) * 3):
                dataout.write(new_list[a] + ' ')


    def flattenred():
        for colour in range (0,len(self.pixels),3):
            self.pixels [colour]=str[0]


    def writetofile(self):
        dataout= open(self.outfile,"w")
        dataout.write(self.type +"\n" + self.columns + "\n" + self.row +"\n"+ self.colour +"\n"+ " ".join (self.pixels))


sample= PPM("cake.ppm", "Replica.ppm")
sample.writetofile()
sample.flattenred()
sample.flip_horizontal
```

Comment: what do you mean by `str[0]` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Create a 2d lists with the smaller lists containing the rgb values and append lists of lists
def horizontal_flip(self):
    if int(self.columns) > 1000:
        return "ERROR!! Number of columns is larger than what can be held in a buffer."
    else:
        temp_list = []
        for b in range(int(self.row)):
            column_list = []
            column_list += self.pixels[0:int(self.columns) * 3]
            self.pixels = self.pixels[int(self.columns) * 3 : ]
            temp_list.append(column_list)
        #print temp_list
        new_list = []
        for i in range(int(len(temp_list))):
            new_list.append (temp_list[i][0])
            new_list.append (temp_list[i][1])
            new_list.append (temp_list[i][2])
            temp_list[i] = temp_list[i][::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go through the first part of the program, and show you how to make it work. You can then apply what I show you to the rest of the program. I have pasted your code below, and I will add comments above the lines which need to be changed.

```
class PPM(object):
    def __init__(self, infile, outfile):
        self.infile=infile
        self.outfile=outfile

        #Read in data of image

        #!!! If you want `data` to be accessible from other functions in
        #!!! the class you need to use `self.data`. You can then define
        #!!! other functions using `def my_cool_function(self):, and access
        #!!! it using `self.data`.
        #!!! The corrected line is as follows:

        #self.data = open(self.infile, "r")
        data= open(self.infile,"r")

        #!!! Similarly, you should use `self.datain` and `self.splits`
        #!!! instead of `datain` and `splits`. i.e.

        #self.datain=data.read()
        #self.splits=datain.split()

        datain=data.read()
        splits=datain.split()

        #Header info
        self.type=splits[0]
        self.columns=splits[1]
        self.row=splits[2]
        self.colour=splits[3]
        self.pixels=splits[4:]


    #!!! Here you need to pass `self` as an argument of the function
    #!!! Otherwise, you won't be able to access the attributes you defined
    #!!! earlier in the `__init__()` function.

    #def greysscale(self):

    def greysscale():

            #!!! This line is indented 8 spaces, but your other indentations
            #!!! are only 4 spaces. Python is very fussy about consistent
            #!!! indentation. You should "dedent" this line (and the five 
            #!!! following lines) in order to maintain a consistent 4 space
            #!!! indent. (Example is shown after this section.)
            #!!! Also, `rows` should be `self.row`
            for row in range(rows):

                #!!! `columns` should be `self.columns`
                for column in range(columns):


                    #!!! Where did you define image?
                    #!!! If it was outside the class, you will need to
                    #!!! pass it to the class in the `__init__()` function,
                    #!!! and use `self.image.getPixel`.
                    r, g, b = image.getPixel(row, column)
                    brightness = int(round(0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b))
                    image.setPixel(row, column, color_rgb(brightness, brightness, brightness))

        #!!! Corrected (but commented out) example.
        #for row in range(self.row):
        #    for column in range(self.columns):
        #        r, g, b = image.getPixel(row, column)
        #        brightness = int(round(0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b))
        #        image.setPixel(row, column, color_rgb(brightness, brightness, brightness))
```

When you are finished correcting it, according to my comments above, you should end up with something like this:

```
class PPM(object):
    def __init__(self, infile, outfile):
        self.infile=infile
        self.outfile=outfile

        #Read in data of image
        self.data = open(self.infile, "r")
        self.datain=data.read()
        self.splits=datain.split()

        #Header info
        self.type=splits[0]
        self.columns=splits[1]
        self.row=splits[2]
        self.colour=splits[3]
        self.pixels=splits[4:]


    def greysscale(self):
        for row in range(self.row):
            for column in range(self.columns):

                #!!! You will still have to fix `image`.
                #!!! I don't know how / where you defined it, so
                #!!! I can't show you how to fix it.
                r, g, b = image.getPixel(row, column)
                brightness = int(round(0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b))
                image.setPixel(row, column, color_rgb(brightness, brightness, brightness))
```

Now it's your turn. Go through the remaining functions, and change them. Remember that when you define them, you need to define them like this:

```
def my_cool_function(self, other, arguments): # NOTE `self` is first!
    print("I am so cool.")
    print(self.name, "is so cool too.") # Assume `self.name` was defined in 
                                        # the `__init__()` function.
```